# Delete draft SMS in android

Tags: android

I want to delete draft SMS. I am able to delete inbox SMS. How can i delete draft SMS ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dont you care enough to mark an answer as the correct answer, once your problem is solved.?

Comment: i do marking for correct answers, But the problem was not solved yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
private void deleteDrafts() {
    /*
     * This will delete all drafts from Messaging App.
     */
    try { 
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/draft"); 
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", 
                "person", "date", "body" }, null, null, null); 

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) { 
            do { 
                long id = c.getLong(0); 
                getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null); 
            } while (c.moveToNext()); 
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) { 

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try as to delete draft SMS

```
this.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/draft"),
                          "_id=?", new String[]{"PASS_DRAFT_SMS_ID_HERE"});
```