# Delete sms from draft box

Tags: android, sms

I found some topic but they were not helped me to solve my problem. I want to delete my draft sms. Have tried with this uri so many time:

```
  contentResolver.delete("content://sms/draft", " ", null); //this is line 173
```

It throws this exeption:

```
 09-09 00:43:43.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2933): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL
 09-09 00:43:43.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java)
 09-09 00:43:43.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java)
 09-09 00:43:43.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.delete(ContentProviderNative.java)
 09-09 00:43:43.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):    at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java)
 09-09 00:43:43.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):    at com.haanz.smsbackup.SmsProvider.query(SmsProvider.java:173)
 09-09 00:43:43.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):    at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java)
 09-09 00:43:43.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java)
 09-09 00:43:43.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java)
 09-09 00:43:43.454: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java)
```

Anybody please tell me where did I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Uri deleteUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
getContentResolver().delete(deleteUri, "type=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(3)});
```

Comment: I have another question. I'm freshman in Android and trying to use Content Provider for an app about SMS. I wondering why, sometime, UriMatcher does not match the uri's pattern, example, in my code:
     
      
     `private static final int RETRIEV_SMS = 15;
     uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "/retriev_data/*/restore/#", RETRIEV_SMS);`

In `query()` method I have gave 

     `cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI + "/retriev_data/" + box_index + "/restore/" + backup_id), null, null, null, null);`

and expect it jump in to `case RETRIEV_SMS:  ` but it does not. :(

Answer (score 0):

did just make a sample project and tested it..

Add to your Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```

And try the code from SO

```
private void deleteDrafts() {
    /*
     * This will delete all drafts from Messaging App.
     */
    try {
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/draft");
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uriSms,
                new String[] { "_id", }, null, null, null);

        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long id = c.getLong(0);
                Log.d("Delete Draft ID", "" + id);
                getContentResolver().delete(
                        Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("error", "" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Between its a duplicate from : [Delete draft SMS in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702196/delete-draft-sms-in-android)

But did test and verify it working.

Comment: Thanks for reply, too! :) Also expect your ideas to clear up my mind on above comment.